# Como redirigir con .htaccess un subdominio?

Tags: .htaccess, dominio

En mi .htaccess he creado una regla que redirige un subdominio a mi dominio principal, pero pasa que los subdominios son dinámicos, he puesto un record CNAME en mi hosting hacia el dominio que identifica que cuando haya un subdominio sepa que es un alias del dominio principal, bien hasta ahí, luego con mi .htaccess quiero que cuando el subdominio ej: http://subdomainaleatorio.domain.com redirija a http://dominio.com, abajo dejo lo mencionado mas arriba.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.domain\.com/$1 [L]
```

y el record seria este:

```
Name            TTL     Class   Type    Record
*.domain.com    1200    IN      CNAME   domain.com
```

el problema que tengo es que cuando trato de acceder a un subdominio dinámico parece que no llega a leer el .htaccess y la regla no se cumple, el servidor me muestra un mensaje donde me dice que este dominio no existe.

Como lograría lo que quiero hacer si esta no es la forma correcta?

Comment: Que es mensaje exacto? Hasta donde se el Apache no tiene tal mensaje.